# Using Cholesky decomposition to solve a system of equaions $A^TAx=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I am looking for a way to use $LL^T$ decomposition of a tridiagonal and symmetric positive definite $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ to solve  $$A^TAx=b.$$ In this case, thanks to $A$ being symmetric, the sysytem is equal to $A^2x=b$. I am not sure how to use the factorization to solve the system though. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient, but assuming you don't wan't to just recalculate the new Cholesky decomposition for $A^2$, you can simply use three forward / back substitutions instead of the usual two, noting that $L^2$ is also triangular:
$$A^T A x = L^T L^2 L^T x = b$$
$$\text{Forward substitute to get $y$:}\quad  L^T y = b,\ y = L^2 L^T x$$
$$\text{Backward substitute to get $z$:}\quad  L^2 z = y, \ z = L^T x$$
$$\text{Forward substitute to get $x$:}\quad  L^T x = z$$

Addendum: As you may already know, the [Cholesky decomposition for a tridiagonal symmetric matrix](http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/ICM/LecturesAndSeminars/08OctMaterials/1/Slide3.pdf) is composed of bidiagonal matrices.

Comment: Yes, I have to use the factorization of the original matrix due to the formulation of my assignment. Unfortunately my first attempt at implementing it yields incorrect results. I'll review my code and get back to you in a bit if i'm unable to find the issue. 

EDIT: I've made a mistake in my assumptions. The code might be working just fine(I have to do some testing)